# yii queryAll failes pass parameter

Tags: php, mysql, yii, dao

I am passing:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll(true,array(':bizid'=>$params));
```

The query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(BI.item_name)
 FROM items BI 
 WHERE BI.b_id IN (:bizid) ORDER BY BI.item_name ASC
```

The query failes to find results, but this query gets the results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(BI.item_name) as i_name FROM blacklist_items BI WHERE BI.business_id IN   (165,664,842,866,1234,3007,3030,3031,3032) ORDER BY BI.item_name ASC
```

Why does queryAll fail?

Comment: You need a separate placeholder for each possible value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529406/how-to-bind-array-parameters-in-yii-framework?rq=1

Comment: It is because of the failure to create a proposer index for the results. It does not like something like $results['DISTINCT(BI.item_name)']. However, $results['i_name'] is good.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the ids to an array:

```
$ids = [165,664,842,866,1234,3007,3030,3031,3032];
```

The query should be:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT(BI.item_name)"
 . " FROM items BI"
 . " WHERE BI.b_id IN (" . implode(',', $ids) . ") ORDER BY BI.item_name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Having come across this problem a few times in my projects I have come-up with the following Yii work-around using CDbCriteria which is a little hacky, but gives the security of param count matching.

When applied to your example my code would be:

```
$business_ids = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('business_id',$business_ids);

$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT(item_name) 
          FROM items 
         WHERE '.$criteria->condition.'
      ORDER BY item_name ASC';

$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
$results = $command->queryColumn($criteria->params);
```