# PHP PDO Query with a number of conditions taken from the array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

I have a few conditions that I want to do in a single query. The base query:

```
$query = "select * from table1
    inner join 
        table2 on table1.id=table2.id
    where 
        ".$condition."
    limit 0,100;";
```

I have array of values ​​to query:

```
$Var = array(
    1 => array('name' => 'somename1','value' => 'somevalue1'),
    2 => array('name' => 'somename2','value' => 'somevalue2'),
    3 => array('name' => 'somename3','value' => 'somevalue3'),
    4 => array('name' => 'somename4','value' => 'somevalue4')
)
```

Now in loop

```
foreach($Var as $Array){  
    $condition .= '(T1_column1 = '.$Array['name'].' and T2_column1 = '.$Array['value'].') or ';
}
```

Final result:

```
$query = "select * from table1
    inner join 
        table2 on table1.id=table2.id
    where 
        (T1_column1 = somename1 and T2_column1 = somevalue1) or  
        (T1_column1 = somename2 and T2_column1 = somevalue2) or  
        (T1_column1 = somename3 and T2_column1 = somevalue3) or  
        (T1_column1 = somename4 and T2_column1 = somevalue4)
    limit 0,100;";
```

Is there a way to do the same thing using PDO: prepare,bindvalue,execute ? or bindValue in foreach loop has the same effect? how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [PDO bind unknown number of parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071619/pdo-bind-unknown-number-of-parameters)

For your convenience, this is code from Paystey's answer modified to fit your example:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
    WHERE ';
foreach($Var as $Array)
{
    $sql .= '(T1_column1 = ? and T2_column1 = ?) or ';
    $binds[] = $Array['name'];
    $binds[] = $Array['value'];
}
$prep = $db->prepare(substr($sql,0,-3) . 'limit 0,100');
$i = 0;
foreach($binds as $bind){
   $prep->bindValue(++$i, $bind);
}
$prep->execute();
```

Not tested.